# T4 Template Linq not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, t4

I try to work with T4 Template within VB.NET.
For test purposes, I created a Console Project in `Visual Studio 2015`.
And added a `.tt` file with the following Code:

```
    <#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="VB" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.Windows.Forms" #>    
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>    
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>    
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>    
<#@ assembly name="System.Linq" #>    
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Resources" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel.Design" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Core" #> 
<#
    Dim myNameSpace As String = "Errors"
    Dim myClassName As String = "GetErrors"
    Dim myTypeOfResourceManager As String = "[Enums].TypeOfResourceManager.Test"
    Dim myResourcePath As String = "Resource"

    Dim myFileName As String = "Test.resx"
    Dim myFilePath As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Me.Host.ResolvePath("")), myResourcePath, myFileName)
    Dim myReader= New ResXResourceReader(myFilePath)

    myreader.UseResXDataNodes = true
    Dim myDateTime As String  = Date.Now.ToString

    Dim myProperties As String()
    Dim myProperty As String

    Dim doc = XDocument.Load(myFilePath)

    Dim myEntries  = From d As XElement In doc.Root.Elements("data")
                        Select New With {
                           Key .Name = d.Attribute("name").Value, _
                           Key .Value = d.Element("value").Value, _
                           Key .Comment = d.Element("comment").Value}

#>
```

The Problem is, that I always get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Compiling transformation: Expression of type 'Object' is not
>   queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or
>   namespace import for the LINQ provider.

I found this Information from MS:

> [https://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/bb763092(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/us-en/library/bb763092(v=vs.110).aspx)

But I did all the Imports. 
What am I missing? - Please help - THX

The most interesting Thing is: I have the idea from [here](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/5497578#file-strings-tt)

When I copy this `C#` Template into my Project, it works. But with the similar `VB.NET` Version I get the above error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
```

I think the rest is fine.